# Sign in with google plus in android app

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I followed this https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started and this https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people guide but still I am unable to get user data.

Current situation:
I press sign in button. That executes `mGoogleApiClient.connect()`
For first time it makes me choose google account.
After that `onConnected` method is called.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d("asd", "connected");
    Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);

    // After that  fetch data
    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
        Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

        String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
        Log.d("asd", "preson name " + personName);
    }
    mShouldResolve = false;
}
```

then `onResult` method is called

```
@Override
public void onResult(People.LoadPeopleResult result) {
    Log.d("asd", "result.getStatus():" + result.getStatus());
}
```

That prints out

> result.getStatus():Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}

Why my `Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)` is always null?

I am using emulator with API 19 Google APIs and for certificate fingerprint I use debug SHA1

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that in manifest provided package name was incorrect.